# How to solve ƒ Object() { [native code] } error while process word tokens?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Consider an array of N items.

```
data = [
  {"source":"post","target":"incident"},
  {"source":"incident","target":"analysis"},
  {"source":"october","target":"post"},
  {"source":"mef","target":"composing"},
  {"source":"trend","target":"archive"},
  {"source":"object","target":"constructor"},
  {"source":"constructor","target":"parameter"}
]
```

I have a function that creates -based on this data- a matrix of nodes. Let's say:

```
[[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

This function works fine with a given data. However, I noted that in this specific *sources* and *targets* it returns an error. The problem is the word: `constructor` in it. If I changed for example **constructor** to **constructr**, the functions will return the matrix.

I found the problem in this part:

```
let nodes = {}
data.map(link => {
  nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = 1)
  nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = 1)
})
nodes = d3.keys(nodes)
nodes.sort()
```

After this process, `nodes` only contains this data: `["analysis", "archive", "composing", "incident", "mef", "object", "october", "parameter", "post", "trend"]` but constructor is missing.

When I try to console some data: this specific node returns this: `ƒ Object() { [native code] }`.

I fixed this issue converting each word in upper case `toUpperCase()`. However, I would like to know if there is other alternative to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most objects in javascript have a constructor method - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor

Thanks to the comment by user2864740 - code that is close to the original in logic - uses `.hasOwnProperty` - since `constructor` is inherited, this will be false, until you explicitly assign it

```js
data = [
  {"source":"post","target":"incident"},
  {"source":"incident","target":"analysis"},
  {"source":"october","target":"post"},
  {"source":"mef","target":"composing"},
  {"source":"trend","target":"archive"},
  {"source":"object","target":"constructor"},
  {"source":"constructor","target":"parameter"}
]
let nodes = {};

data.forEach(link => {
  nodes.hasOwnProperty(link.source) || (nodes[link.source] = 1);
  nodes.hasOwnProperty(link.target) || (nodes[link.target] = 1);
})
nodes = Object.keys(nodes)
nodes.sort()
console.log(nodes.join());
```

Or, you could use `Object.create(null);`

Please read the caveats when using `Object.create(null)` in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#Custom_and_Null_objects

As long as you know the limitations, you shouldn't have any issues

```js
data = [
  {"source":"post","target":"incident"},
  {"source":"incident","target":"analysis"},
  {"source":"october","target":"post"},
  {"source":"mef","target":"composing"},
  {"source":"trend","target":"archive"},
  {"source":"object","target":"constructor"},
  {"source":"constructor","target":"parameter"}
]
let nodes = Object.create(null);

data.forEach(link => {
  nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = 1)
  nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = 1)
})
nodes = Object.keys(nodes)
nodes.sort()
console.log(nodes.join());
```

Of course, the reason why your code fails is because nodes already has `constructor` property (and many others)

so

```
nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = 1)
```

is

```
nodes.constructor || (nodes.constructor = 1)
```

and since nodes.constructor is `truthy` it's never "overwritten" with value 1

you could simply do

```
  nodes[link.source] = 1;
  nodes[link.target] = 1;
```

with identical results, there's actually no need to do this:

```
  nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = 1);
  nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = 1);
```

see the following snippet:

```js
data = [
  {"source":"post","target":"incident"},
  {"source":"incident","target":"analysis"},
  {"source":"october","target":"post"},
  {"source":"mef","target":"composing"},
  {"source":"trend","target":"archive"},
  {"source":"object","target":"constructor"},
  {"source":"constructor","target":"parameter"}
]
let nodes = {};

data.forEach(link => {
  nodes[link.source] = 1;
  nodes[link.target] = 1;
})
nodes = Object.keys(nodes)
nodes.sort()
console.log(nodes.join());
```

Comment: [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) might also be relevant here (use the version/example with `.call` to avoid the case then `hasOwnProperty` is one the names!). That can be used to ensure that a prototype-inherited won't be "matched": ie. the property has to be 'truthy' and has-to-be-my-own. This is same issue as the classical `for(..in..)` "buggy" code.

Comment: @user2864740 - very good, yes, I always forget about `hasOwnProperty`

Comment: I've added code that uses `hasOwnProperty` - that's probably the best solution :p